# Smart search Indexer duplicate entry mysql error

Tags: mysql, smartsearch

I'm running Joomla 3.3.1 with MySQL 5.6.21 and I'm getting the following error when running an Index. It indexes 2 items and then stops.

> An Error Has Occurred
>
> **Duplicate entry '1-0' for key 'PRIMARY'**
>   SQL=INSERT INTO `b83d9z9_finder_links_terms0` (`link_id`, `term_id`, `weight`) SELECT
>   1, `term_id`, ROUND(SUM(`context_weight`), 8) FROM
>   `b83d9z9_finder_tokens_aggregate` WHERE `map_suffix` = '0' GROUP BY
>   `term` ORDER BY `term` DESC

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: if the solution below worked for you, please award the green tick.  If it didn't, but you solved the issue another way, please post an answer and "accept" it.  If you still don't know a solution, please state this fact and if you have any additional details then update your question.  All questions should progress toward a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a very similar error...

> **Duplicate entry '14-6' for key 'PRIMARY'**
>
> SQL=INSERT INTO
>   `#__finder_links_terms4` (`link_id`, `term_id`, `weight`) SELECT 14,
>   `term_id`, ROUND(SUM(`context_weight`), 8) FROM
>   `#__finder_tokens_aggregate` WHERE `map_suffix` = '4' GROUP BY `term`
>   ORDER BY `term` DESC

...and solved this by clicking the 'Clear Index' button at the top. After that I was able to index my files.

Comment: I have the same error, but this didn't fix it., still looking for a solution, have clear the index, remapping all tables, fix all index and auto_increments... but nothing fix the error...